# Sitecore 8 - How to set display name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore 8, I want to set the Display Name of an item inside the content editor. There was a toolbar button in Sitecore 7 but it doesnt exist on any toolbar in 8 ..

I need to specify the display name as the string includes an ampersand.

Thanks, this should be so easy but cant see how!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button is in the same place as in Sitecore 7. Select the item in the tree and in the Home ribbon bar there is a button for Display name:

[image]

Alternatively - if you enable **Standard Fields** from the **View** ribbon bar, you can edit the field under the **Appearance** section:

[image]

Both of those options should be accessible by an author account.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, Im not seeing the Home ribbon bar but viewing the standard fields worked for me.

Comment: @SteveWard, if you see the tabs, but not the rest of the ribbon, double click on the tabs to expand the ribbon open again.